# Integration of hadoop (specifically HDFS files) with ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, hdfs, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am trying to integrate hadoop with ELK stack.
My use case is " i have to get a data from a file present in HDFS path and show the contents on kibana dashboard"

Hive is not working there so I can't use hive.
Are there any other ways to do that?

Anybody is having any article with step by step process?

I have tried to get logs from a linux location on a hadoop server through logstash and filebeat but that is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for some OSINT work it is quite easy to do once one can get the content out of hdfs into a local filesystem. That's done by setting up a [HdfsNfsGateway](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html). Once that's done use [filebeat and logstash](https://www.javainuse.com/elasticsearch/filebeat-elk) to import your content into elasticsearch. After that just configure your [kibana dashboard](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-kibana-dashboards-and-visualizations) for the index your using.